# Why is diarrhea often accompanied by sweat? What is the function of the sweat in this process?

Tags: body-temperature, sweat, diarrhea, function, stools

Why is diarrhea often accompanied by sweat?

I have noticed that when I or my significant other gets a bout of diarrhea -- that sweating often manifests itself too (moments before and during the process). What causes this?

Comment: I've never experienced that but I would imagine it's a vagal response.

Answer (score -3):

According to sources - Diarrhea is caused mainly due to viral infections
and food poisoning.Cramps, Sweats, and diarrhea can go along due to infection in the uterus or intestines.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what type of infections in the intestines that cause diarrhea? So I know what to tell my Dr. when I speak to him.

Comment: @PillsNPillows You don't need to explain to a physician what causes diarrhea. They will explain that to you.

Comment: Although sweating may go with fevers, the question asks about sweating that occurs "moments before and during" the bout of diarrhea. That's not how the sweating from a fever occurs; it is continuous.